# Pass a predicate filter to FindAllTasks(Predicate<Task> filter, bool)

Tags: c#

In windows, c#, I want to find a list of Tasks whose names contain "XYZ" in Task Scheduler to start them all. TaskService has a method `FindAllTasks(Predicate<Task> filter, bool)`, so

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
{
    foreach(Task f in ts.FindAllTasks( x => x.Name.ToUpper().Contains("*XYZ*"), true ))
        {
            f.Run();
        }
}
```

compiled ok, but not finding it when there is at least one task match the filter, and `ts` shows it in the list.

Comment: You don't want the stars ( `Contains("XYZ")` ).  May be other issues

Comment: what if my wildcard is **XYZ*1* ?

Comment: Then use regexes or `Contains() && Contains()`.  See also `EndsWith()`  Contains() does not accept wildcards:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When you read documentation on `Contains` did it ever mentions wildcards? (it does not even support case insensitive match :) )

Comment: @zzxyz no star works!

Answer (score 0):

Predicate sounds scary, indeed just a filter condition. The point is like zzxyz and Alexei pointed out, `.Contains()` does not take wildcard.